# Python dictionary storing it in reverse

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

When i store a dictionary as below i get the dictionary variable in reverse order

when i store a disctionary variable as

```
nm={'key1': 'v1', 'key2': 'v2', 'key3': 'v3'}
```

nm reads me as in a reverse order

```
{'key3': 'v3', 'key2': 'v2', 'key1': 'v1'}
```

could somebody help me why is it storing the disctionary key and values in a reverse order?

-pasha

Comment: It is not reversed. It is just lacking the order that you expect.

Comment: I've upvoted the question because it's useful for people new to Python dicts. Yes it's trivial (if you're an RTFM junkie), but it's  a common trap for many.  Oh, and RTFM :) https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 3):

You may try this:

```
>>> x = OrderedDict((('key1', 'v1'), ('key2', 'v2'),('key3', 'v3')))
>>> x
OrderedDict([('key1', 'v1'), ('key2', 'v2'),('key3', 'v3')])
>>> items = x.items()
>>> items.reverse()
>>> OrderedDict(items)
OrderedDict([('key3', 'v3'), ('key2', 'v2'),('key1', 'v1')])
```

Note that Dictionaries are not ordered in Python. Also check **[class collections.OrderedDict([items])](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)**

Comment: Often newbies expect `OrderedDict` to be 'SortedDict'. You might want to mention the only order is the insertion order.

Answer (score 2):

[Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) are not ordered in Python. Specifically:

> CPython implementation detail: Keys and values are listed in an
>   arbitrary order which is non-random, varies across Python
>   implementations, and depends on the dictionary’s history of insertions
>   and deletions.

If order is important, use a list of tuples:

```
>>> nm=[('key1', 'v1'), ('key2', 'v2'), ('key3', 'v3')]
```

Or an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). You should know that 'order' in this case is just based on insertion order; not any form of sorting.

You can also sort a dicts output:

```
>>> demo={'key'+str(i): 'v'+str(i) for i in range(15)}
>>> demo
{'key9': 'v9', 'key8': 'v8', 'key3': 'v3', 'key2': 'v2', 'key1': 'v1', 'key0': 'v0', 'key7': 'v7', 'key6': 'v6', 'key5': 'v5', 'key4': 'v4', 'key14': 'v14', 'key13': 'v13', 'key12': 'v12', 'key11': 'v11', 'key10': 'v10'}
>>> import re
>>> sorted(demo.items(), key=lambda t: int(re.search(r'(\d+)', t[0]).group(1)))
[('key0', 'v0'), ('key1', 'v1'), ('key2', 'v2'), ('key3', 'v3'), ('key4', 'v4'), ('key5', 'v5'), ('key6', 'v6'), ('key7', 'v7'), ('key8', 'v8'), ('key9', 'v9'), ('key10', 'v10'), ('key11', 'v11'), ('key12', 'v12'), ('key13', 'v13'), ('key14', 'v14')]
```

Or, better still, write a generator to yield the key, values in a order you want:

```
def kf(s):
    try:
        return int(re.search(r'(\d+)', s).group(1))
    except AttributeError:
        return s    

def sorted_dict(di, kf=kf):
    for k in sorted(di.keys(), key=kf):
        yield k, di[k]    

>>> list(sorted_dict(demo))
[('key0', 'v0'), ('key1', 'v1'), ('key2', 'v2'), ('key3', 'v3'), ('key4', 'v4'), ('key5', 'v5'), ('key6', 'v6'), ('key7', 'v7'), ('key8', 'v8'), ('key9', 'v9'), ('key10', 'v10'), ('key11', 'v11'), ('key12', 'v12'), ('key13', 'v13'), ('key14', 'v14')]
```

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary is not supposed to have an order!
The order is undefined:

Take `nm={'key1': 'v1', 'key2': 'v2', 'key3': 'v3', 'key4':'v4'}`
it shows as `{'key3': 'v3', 'key2': 'v2', 'key1': 'v1', 'key4': 'v4'}`